WPF animation sometimes suddenly stops partway
I have a control that displays a curve with control points that the user can control. If the user drags a control point outside of the bounds of the control, it is no longer reachable, and so I create a little animation that scales the curve down until all of the control points are visible again. I am using a RectAnimation on a DependencyProperty in a surrogate object type to capture the values produced by the animation. This is mostly working, except that randomly, perhaps one time out of ten, the animation suddenly stops partway, no exception, no Completed event, and the curve hasn't been fully translated to the target bounds.
Slightly-simplified code:
  Rect elementBounds = GetBoundsForControlPoints();

  if ((elementBounds.Left < 0) || (elementBounds.Right > ActualWidth)
   || (elementBounds.Top < 0) || (elementBounds.Bottom > ActualHeight))
  {
    var fitBounds = FitRectangleToVisibleArea(elementBounds); // same aspect but entirely visible

    var anim = new RectAnimation();

    anim.From = elementBounds;
    anim.To = fitBounds;
    anim.Duration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.4);

    var animTarget = new AnimationTarget();

    animTarget.StartRect = elementBounds;
    animTarget.EndRect = fitBounds;
    
    animTarget.RectChanged +=
      (_, _) =>
      {
        TranslateControlPoints(animTarget.StartRect, animTarget.Rect);
      };

    animTarget.BeginAnimation(AnimationTarget.RectProperty, anim);
  }

This is the proxy class:
  class AnimationTarget : UIElement
  {
    public static DependencyProperty RectProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(nameof(Rect), typeof(Rect), typeof(AnimationTarget), new UIPropertyMetadata(RectChangedCallback));

    public Rect StartRect;
    public Rect EndRect;

    public Rect Rect
    {
      get => (Rect)GetValue(RectProperty);
      set => SetValue(RectProperty, value);
    }

    public event EventHandler? RectChanged;

    static void RectChangedCallback(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
      ((AnimationTarget)d).RectChanged?.Invoke(d, EventArgs.Empty);
    }
  }

Most of the time, the animation runs to completion perfectly, but every now and then, it just ... stops. The curve is partway along its translation and simply stays there. I can trigger a new animation and it picks up from where the previous one left off.
What might be causing the animations to sometimes just stop partway through?

I have a wrapper around my storyboards with "expected results" that are checked at "completed" or "stopped", which gives me what I need to work with when debugging. While your durations seem to be constant, there's no way of knowing if your boundary assumptions are correct.

Hmm, I don't see a "stopped" event in animation objects...

I didn't say "event". The alternative to letting an animation run to completion, is to "stop" it; which requires it's own "handling sequence" in order to "sync" the visual to the actuals. Users can "speed up" or slow down my animations; which requires thinking outside the "storyboard box". I also "chain" them.

Ah, okay. So you've never had an animation just suddenly stop partway without your code telling it to.

If you mean "crash", I can crash my stories if I don't "stop" them before modifying them. I can't afford to have my animations stop for no reason because that "is" the bulk of the app (so the pattern is tested to no end with all the "checks" in place: limits; is / is not animating; is rotating; is scaling; etc) Serious business these animations :0)

Nope, it's not crashing. It just... stops. I can make a change that triggers a new animation, and that one usually runs to completion. Sometimes it stops too.

After the kids are in bed, I'll see if I can capture a video of it.

This video shows the behaviour: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NT1Y1WGoygU
Look at the video description for details.

Animations run independent of one's code. You can hit a breakpoint in your code, which stops the "code", while the animation continues to run in the "visual layer". In order to "see" what the animation is doing, and going to do, I have a "monitor" that runs in parallel; a timer that runs every second that computes the current position of each animation using the render transforms, and compares that with expected results. The objective is to detect "collisions" and other stuff.

So, I avoid problems in the first place through "transparency". That was my original point: one needs more transparency when dealing with animations, which operate more or less independent of the code that launches it.

And, using other than the "transforms" (rotation, scaling, translating, skewing) to animate properties, one "may" have issues. E.g. It is "preferred" (?) that one use a Scaling transform instead of a "width and / or height" animation ... and sync to actuals (only) if and when needed. (Independent vs dependent animations; yours appear "dependent")

"Dependent" animations trigger layout changes; independent ones don't.

As a final note, I only resorted to "Storyboards" after exhausting my own "animating" techniques. If I needed to, I would move stuff around "in code" using a timer. You can do a lot in a few ms.

My animation isn't focused on moving an object in the visual tree. As you can see in the video, I am animating a property on a surrogate object and when the value get changed, I am setting new locations for curve points, which then feeds into the UI in a separate way. The property being animated is of type Rect and it is the only property on the object, so scale and translation is not relevant to my situation. Since this surrogate/proxy object is just a stand-alone Rect property, it isn't in the visual tree and thus any machinations from layouts aren't relevant to the animation.

I guess I will simply have to write my own animation code. But that definitely feels like  a blind workaround. It doesn't help to understand why the animations are just abruptly stopping sometimes.

What is a "Rect"? It is Left, Top, Width, and Height. These are "translation" and "scaling" "dependent" properties. I "animate" my user controls using these properties, but via "transforms". As I said, dependent animations trigger layout updates. The "visual layer" is intended to run at 60 FPS. If your animation "can't", it probably gets kicked into the UI thread; which is now flooded with updates. (Just an assumption).

That would explain poor performance (which I am not in practice seeing), but I don't see how it explains WPF giving up on the animation partway through. :-P

Your manipultion of "control points" is "random". If as a result, something goes "negative" (Width, for example), that would explain it.  That is one explanation. I'm sure there are others.

In my testing, I drag control points out in all directions. Being negative should have no impact at all -- and also, how would the animation know about it? My assignment of updated values is in a try/catch. Even if it were throwing exceptions, it should keep firing animation ticks.

Based on your approach, you are not able to confirm the values of the Storyboard at the time the animation stops, so you are just speculating. And as I said before, the animation is not "running your code" (other than at completion), so there is nothing to "catch". As far as "negative awareness" is concerned, if you tell an animation to vary a width of say, 100, by -110, (using the "By" pattern "over time"), what do you think might happen?

That isn't possible. The animation is from one Rect to another Rect. As long as the start Rect and end Rect are well-formed, every intermediate Rect will be well-formed as well. Anyway, I'm ready to put the issue behind me. As far as I'm concerned, WPF animations have a reliability issue. I don't know what it is, but the animation code I posted in my Answer to this question does not have a similar issue.

Well, I don't have an answer in the sense of explaining the underlying behaviour. But I do have an answer in the sense of eliminating the problem: I implemented the animation myself.
I created my own RectAnimation class that has members From, To, Duration, Completed and which merges in the AnimationTarget class from my previous implementation, providing a Rect DependencyProperty and RectChanged event.
When BeginAnimation is called, it starts a Thread (with IsBackground set to true) which captures start time, end time (start time + duration), start rect and end rect (to ensure that there cannot be outside changes), then enters a loop. Each time through the loop, it gets the current DateTime and computes a progress value (double, 0.0 to 1.0), breaking out of the loop if the progress is out of range (e.g. if the end time has been reached), then passes that progress to a method AnimationTick. A brief delay limits the theoretical maximum framerate to 100fps.
AnimationTick computes the intermediate Rect value for the supplied progress and then begins the process of assigning it to the dependency property. This is a process because, being a dependency property, the assignment can only be done on the correct thread. Dispatcher.BeginInvoke is used to queue the change, and the code ensures that there is only one outstanding assignment at any point in time, just in case the UI queue gets backed up. Because of this, even if it computes 100 updates per second, if it is only updating the UI e.g. 30 times a second then the Rect property will be updated 30 times a second.
Use of the class is pretty similar to use of the system RectAnimation, with the main difference being that it animates a property directly on my RectAnimation class instead of being executed on a specified property of some other object.
        class RectAnimation : UIElement
        {
            public static DependencyProperty RectProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(nameof(Rect), typeof(Rect), typeof(RectAnimation), new UIPropertyMetadata(RectChangedCallback));

            public Rect StartRect;
            public Rect EndRect;
            public TimeSpan Duration;

            public event EventHandler? Completed;

            public Rect Rect
            {
                get => (Rect)GetValue(RectProperty);
                set => SetValue(RectProperty, value);
            }

            public void BeginAnimation()
            {
                var thread = new Thread(AnimationThreadProc);

                thread.IsBackground = true;
                thread.Start();
            }

            void AnimationThreadProc()
            {
                try
                {
                    DateTime startTime = DateTime.UtcNow;
                    DateTime endTime = startTime + Duration;

                    var startRect = StartRect;
                    var endRect = EndRect;

                    while (true)
                    {
                        DateTime now = DateTime.UtcNow;

                        double progress = (now - startTime) / Duration;

                        if ((progress < 0.0) || (progress > 1.0))
                            break;

                        AnimationTick(startRect, endRect, progress);

                        Thread.Sleep(10);
                    }

                    Rect = endRect;

                    Completed?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
                }
                catch { }
            }

            bool _tickOutstanding = false;
            RectReference? _tickRect;

            // Allow for atomic updates.
            record RectReference(Rect Value);

            void AnimationTick(Rect startRect, Rect endRect, double progress)
            {
                _tickRect = new RectReference(new Rect(
                    startRect.X + (endRect.X - startRect.X) * progress,
                    startRect.Y + (endRect.Y - startRect.Y) * progress,
                    startRect.Width + (endRect.Width - startRect.Width) * progress,
                    startRect.Height + (endRect.Height - startRect.Height) * progress));

                if (!_tickOutstanding)
                {
                    _tickOutstanding = true;

                    Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(
                        DispatcherPriority.Send,
                        () =>
                        {
                            if (_tickRect != null)
                                Rect = _tickRect.Value;
                            _tickOutstanding = false;
                        });
                }
            }

            public Point TransformPoint(Point pt)
            {
                var currentRect = Rect;

                var relativePosition = pt - StartRect.TopLeft;

                relativePosition.X *= currentRect.Width / StartRect.Width;
                relativePosition.Y *= currentRect.Height / StartRect.Height;

                return (Point)(relativePosition + currentRect.TopLeft);
            }

            public event EventHandler? RectChanged;

            static void RectChangedCallback(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
            {
                ((RectAnimation)d).RectChanged?.Invoke(d, EventArgs.Empty);
            }
        }


While my own animation techniques were more powerful, ultimately the Storyboards were smoother. So you come up with a hybrid.

I haven't observed problems with the smoothness, but in this case, reliability is the priority in any case, so even if it were a little bit less smooth, I'd still opt for the one I can trust. :-)
